# Browsers are lagging when trying to load some webpages

Tags: firefox, performance

I'm facing a problem both on firefox (no addons) & Chrome (on Ubuntu 12.04).

Some sites like Facebook, Ask Ubuntu and Deviant Art are not loading even after 10-15 minutes. Other sites are running quite well (I can play YouTube videos, for example), so the problem seems to be webpage-specific.

What can I do about this?

Comment: In firefox: try see if the error console says anything specific? (from the menu: Tools > Web Developer > Error Console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When random sites are working while others are not I always check for MTU issue (or PMTU discovery) first. I'd recommend trying this and see if that helps:

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

For more information on this: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove your browser cache, in Firefox by selecting "Extras" → "Remove newest history". Make sure, that all the ticks are selected.
It's possible that your computer loaded the webpages wrongly

Comment: i have tried that.. but not only firefox, newly installed chrome or midori are also affected with the same issue..