# Network problem: Chrome would not load sites that Firefox does

Tags: networking, firefox, chromium, wired

I am running a Ubuntu 13.04. I had both Chrome and Firefox installed, and the former does not load most websites. There is no proxy, and I have disabled the firewall. I connect to the internet directly through ethernet port. The computer is in the office, I do not have access to any other hardware  (routers and the sort).

This is the output of certain network commands:

```
root@I39549:~# iptables -t filter --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

root@I39549:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:1f:66:a7:ed:5c  
      inet addr:10.4.3.174  Bcast:10.4.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ca1f:66ff:fea7:ed5c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3165125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:246303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:779916007 (779.9 MB)  TX bytes:28964602 (28.9 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:17170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:17170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1568486 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:1568486 (1.5 MB)


root@I39549:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   I39549

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

root@I39549:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search utadeo.edu.co

root@I39549:~#  arp -a
ET0021B7F27301.local (169.254.1.2) at 00:21:b7:f2:73:01 [ether] on eth0
portatilrok.utadeo.edu.co (10.4.3.213) at a4:1f:72:8b:47:c4 [ether] on eth0
i37386.local (10.4.1.61) at a8:20:66:06:6d:b1 [ether] on eth0
ET000400C16250.local (10.4.5.88) at 00:04:00:c1:62:50 [ether] on eth0
i58068.utadeo.loc (10.4.1.232) at 00:26:2d:1f:88:9a [ether] on eth0
ET0021B7CC3789.local (169.254.1.10) at 00:21:b7:cc:37:89 [ether] on eth0
? (10.4.0.1) at 00:e0:b1:66:b5:60 [ether] on eth0
i36903.utadeo.loc (10.4.1.7) at d4:9a:20:ec:f2:7e [ether] on eth0
ET000400C1C2B5.local (10.4.5.86) at 00:04:00:c1:c2:b5 [ether] on eth0
i36915.utadeo.loc (10.4.1.190) at a8:20:66:06:6c:d3 [ether] on eth0
root@I39549:~# ping localhost 
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.026/0.035/0.053/0.014 ms
root@I39549:~# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.229.211) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mia04s05-in-f19.1e100.net (74.125.229.211): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=46.8 ms
64 bytes from mia04s05-in-f19.1e100.net (74.125.229.211): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=46.3 ms
64 bytes from mia04s05-in-f19.1e100.net (74.125.229.211): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=45.9 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 45.958/46.379/46.841/0.438 ms
```

Any ideas on what may be wrong?

I've already tried this:

[browsers are lagging to load some webpages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196468/browsers-are-lagging-to-load-some-webpages)

without any effect.

Comment: Any suspicious extension? Have you seen in dev tools (pressing F12) if there's any error message? (in network tab, check if anything is ever loaded; in console, check if there's any message)

Comment: No extensions yet, nothing in dev tools, nothing when I load it from the Console.

Comment: Might give it a shot by clearing config files and/or checking the chrome/chromium version installed. http://askubuntu.com/questions/3424/chromium-doesnt-work?rq=1